# Using Promises with Queries with Node.JS/NPM's MySQL Library

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm using the `mysql` NPM library with Node.JS and I'm trying to query a database and have the function return a Promise instead of requiring a callback. Here's what I've tried:

index.js:

```
var result = await asyncQuery.main(connection, "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = ?", "1234567890")
```

asyncQuery.js:

```
var colors = require('colors')

module.exports = {
  main: function(con, q, vars) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!vars) {
        con.query(q, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(colors.red(err.stack))

            return reject(err);
          }
          resolve(result)
        })
      }
      else {
        con.query(q, vars, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(colors.red(err.stack))

            return reject(err);
          }
          resolve(result)
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This works fine if no vars/args are passed (`?`), but once a `?` is used, I get an error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

If I were to run a regular query, with a callback, this would work perfectly fine. There's something wrong with `asyncQuery.js`, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

*Does anyone have a fix for this code, or an easier way to achieve my goal? I've heard of the [Promise MySQL Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql), but I'm not sure if it supports Promise **and** callback queries. If it does, let me know and I'll give it a shot.*

NodeJS Version: 9.1.0

NPM Version: 5.5.1

NPM's MySQL Library Version: 2.15.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That exact query works and will not trigger that error, you probably had a more complex query with multiple placeholders, such as:

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = ? or ref_id = ?`,

In that case instead of sending a string, you will need to send an array with as many values as `?` you have.

So just send: `["1234567890", "1234567890"]` instead of a string for the above query.

Furthermore, your method can be simplified into:

```
module.exports = {
    main(con, q, vars) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query(q, vars, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(colors.red(err.stack))

                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(result)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Allowing you to drop the `if/else`.

As a personal note, I prefer the `mysql2` package which already has a [promise wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) and it's faster than `mysql`, with the benefit of having almost the same API.

Comment: Woah this actually worked! What I don't understand is that my example query actually DID work, as I just found out, with**out** the `[]`, but a more complex query needed the `[]`, even though it only had one `?`. Nonetheless, thank you for the response

Comment: alternatively `main: function(con, q, ...vars) {` - or since ES2015 is a thing `main(con, q, ...vars) {`

Comment: @apxx To be honest always sent an object/array, it's now working for me sending a string, but not in every case, so if you provide your query, I can edit my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **mysql-promise** package from npmjs, wich behaves as a wrapper for mysql and mysql2 : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise

Usage example:

```
var db = require('mysql-promise')();

db.configure({
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "foo",
    "password": "bar",
    "database": "db"
});

db.query('UPDATE foo SET key = ?', ['value'])
.then( function(){ return db.query('SELECT * FROM foo'); })
.spread(function (rows) { console.log('Loook at all the foo', rows); });
```